# Accessing entities in EF on basis of userID

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-database-first

I want to be able to define a logic for accessing entities using EF5 . Like my order entity has UserId so i want from any where in code if query hits Orders it needs to get filter by currently logged in user.
I am using database first approach.

Comment: Do you use default or custom membership provider?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a two-phase process.

First, having the username of your user, you retrieve the user record from the data source:

```
string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
User user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault( u => u.UserName == UserName );
```

Then, you filter your data for specific user:

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = context.Orders.Where( o => o.UserId == user.Id );
```

You can further optimize the process so that the user record doesn't have to be retrieved upon each request, instead you could store the UserId in the authentication cookie.